# VBA not recognizing Value of Unbound Textbox for Query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a two unbound textboxes in a Form where the user sets the start and end dates for query.  The user than hits a button to generate report.

Everything works except Access pops up a Dialog Box asking for the start and stop dates even though the variables myStartDate and myEndDate have proper values.

I suspect I am missing something simple here.

```
Private Sub PrintReport_Click()
    Dim myForm As Form
    Dim myTextBox As TextBox
    Dim myStartDate As Date, myEndDate As Date

    myStartDate = CDate(Forms![Data Entry - Ammonia and Alkalinity]![StartDate])
   myEndDate = CDate(Forms![Data Entry - Ammonia and Alkalinity]![EndDate])

   Dim whereString As String
   whereString = "LabDate Between myStartDate And myEndDate"
   DoCmd.OpenReport "Ammonia and Alkalinity Report", acViewPreview, , whereString

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not concatenating the VBA variables in the string. Hence, the report is looking for the `myStartDate` and `myEndDate` within its scope and not passed from VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the string to use these variables.

What you want is:

```
whereString = "LabDate Between #" & myStartDate & "# AND #" & myEndDate & "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you (and I guess so) have applied a *date* format to the two textboxes, you don't need most of the converting, but you must pass formatted string expression for the date values to the SQL code:

```
Private Sub PrintReport_Click()

    Dim myForm As Form
    Dim myTextBox As TextBox
    Dim myStartDate As String
    Dim myEndDate As String
    Dim whereString As String

    myStartDate = Format(Forms![Data Entry - Ammonia and Alkalinity]![StartDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd")
    myEndDate = Format(Forms![Data Entry - Ammonia and Alkalinity]![EndDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd")

    whereString = "LabDate Between #" & myStartDate & "# And #" & myEndDate & "#"
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Ammonia and Alkalinity Report", acViewPreview, , whereString

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Gustav, @OpiesDad got the answer just a bit before you, but I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: Well, it not that simple. If you don't format as shown, the query will fail in a non-US environment. That may not present an issue for you, but there is a world out here.

Comment: True, but I had put a date mask on the textboxes that supply the dates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you mean an InputMask, that makes no difference, neither does the format of the textbox. It's the doubled conversion in your original code with uncontrolled casting to text when concatenating the SQL code you have to modify as shown.

Answer (score -1):

Fix whereString be:-

```
whereString = "LabDate Between " & _
"#" & Format (myStartDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")  & " #" & _
 " And " & _
"#" & Format (myEndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: In where string VBA requests to use mm/dd/yyyy date format, which is not (most of times), the same user date format.